# how to use gzip decompression with AFNetworking API call?

Tags: php, ios, json, gzip, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking library in my projects. recently I heard about gzip data compression which is given by defalut in NSURLConnection Class and reducing the time and loading time of large json response, hence AFNetworking might have that feature as it is working on top of NSURLConnection.

but I do not know how to get gzip compressed json response from php API through AFNetworking.

I need this technique when Json response file size is more that 100kb+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If server supports `gzip` it could **require client to ask** server to respond with `gzip` enabled. To ask server to use `gzip` you **add specific** `"Accept-Encoding"` **header** to your requests. You can do this, for example, with this lines of code:

```
// Get one that serializes your requests, 
// for example from your AFHTTPSessionManager subclass
AFHTTPRequestSerializer <AFURLRequestSerialization> *requestSerializer = ...
[requestSerializer setValue:@"gzip, identity" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
```

`"Accept-Encoding"` header must contain `gzip` while, probably, `identity` is not required.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `NSURLSession` based API in AFNetworking, it would be included automatically as said [here](http://clintmartin.net/2016/03/15/gzipping-ios-apps.html). Thus you don't need to do anything.

Please be noted that you may not see the header value in the app log for request, but you may check the header in response to confirm this behaviour if the server supports gzip.